# How can I check if an argument is defined when starting/calling a batch file?

Tags: batch-file, arguments

I'm trying to use the following validation logic in a batch file but the "usage" block never executes even when no parameter is supplied to the batch file.

```
if ("%1"=="") goto usage

@echo This should not execute

@echo Done.
goto :eof

:usage
@echo Usage: %0 <EnvironmentName>
exit 1
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the proper way to test if a parameter is empty in a batch file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2541767/what-is-the-proper-way-to-test-if-a-parameter-is-empty-in-a-batch-file)

Comment: @double-beep - The question here (by daniel-fortunov) was asked first, about a year before the question you refer to was posted. Which is the (possible) duplicate?

Comment: @KevinFegan because the other question has more views and more answers.

Answer (score 185, accepted):

The check for whether a commandline argument has been set can be `[%1]==[]`, but, as [Dave Costa](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6568/dave-costa) [points out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/830565/how-do-i-check-that-a-parameter-is-defined-when-calling-a-batch-file/830593#830593), `"%1"==""` will also work.

I also fixed a syntax error in the usage echo to escape the greater-than and less-than signs. In addition, the `exit` needs a `/B` argument otherwise `CMD.exe` will quit.

```
@echo off

if [%1]==[] goto usage
@echo This should not execute
@echo Done.
goto :eof
:usage
@echo Usage: %0 ^<EnvironmentName^>
exit /B 1
```

Comment: [%1]==[] is better than "%1"=="" because it will correctly handle the case where %1 itself contains double quotes. "%1"=="" will error with an "unexpected at this time" message.

Comment: Note that, if you aren't using commandline arguments but `set` variables (I don't know the correct batch terminology), you might want to use `"%myvar%"==""` because if `myvar` has spaces in it and is not quoted, you will get the "unexpected at this time" message.

Comment: @Pat SET variables could be checked with `IF NOT DEFINED VarName` block. Also +1 to tukushan for not using quotes in comparison. Just don't do it. Never.

Comment: `"%~1"==""` will also work and take care of the case where %1 has double quotes

Comment: `"%~1"==""` handles spaces in the variable while the `[]` version does not.

Answer (score 29):

> #### A more-advanced example:
>
> ⍟ unlimited arguments.
>
> ⍟ exist on file system (either `file` or `directory`?) or a generic `string`.
>
> ⍟ specify if is a file
>
> ⍟ specify is a directory
>
> ⍟ *no* extensions, would work in legacy scripts!
>
> ⍟ *minimal code ☺*

```
@echo off

:loop
      ::-------------------------- has argument ?
      if ["%~1"]==[""] (
        echo done.
        goto end
      )
      ::-------------------------- argument exist ?
      if not exist %~s1 (
        echo not exist
      ) else (
        echo exist
        if exist %~s1\NUL (
          echo is a directory
        ) else (
          echo is a file
        )
      )
      ::--------------------------
      shift
      goto loop
      
      
:end

pause
```

*✨ other stuff..✨*

■ in `%~1` - the `~` removes any wrapping `"` or `'`.

■ in `%~s1` - the `s` makes the path be `DOS 8.3 naming`, which is a nice trick to avoid spaces in file-name while checking stuff (and this way no need to wrap the resource with more `"`s.

■ the `["%~1"]==[""]` "can not be sure" if the argument is a file/directory or just a generic string yet, so instead the expression uses brackets and the original unmodified `%1` (just without the `"` wrapping, if any..)

if there were no arguments of if we've used `shift` and the arg-list pointer has passed the last one, the expression will be evaluated to `[""]==[""]`.

■ this is as much specific you can be without using more tricks (it would work even in windows-95's batch-scripts...)

#### ■ execution examples

save it as `identifier.cmd`

it can identify an unlimited arguments (normally you are limited to `%1`-`%9`), just remember to wrap the arguments with inverted-commas, or use 8.3 naming, or drag&drop them over (it automatically  does either of above).

---

this allows you to run the following commands:

⓵`identifier.cmd c:\windows`
and to get

```
exist
is a directory
done
```

---

⓶`identifier.cmd "c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Office\OFFICE11\WINWORD.EXE"`
and to get

```
exist
is a file
done
```

---

⓷ and multiple arguments <sub>(of course this is the whole-deal..)</sub>

`identifier.cmd c:\windows\system32 c:\hiberfil.sys "c:\pagefile.sys" hello-world`

and to get

```
exist
is a directory
exist
is a file
exist
is a file
not exist
done.
```

**naturally it can be a lot more complex,**
**but nice examples should always be simple and minimal.** :)

### Hope it helps anyone :)

<sub>published here:[CMD Ninja - Unlimited Arguments Processing, Identifying If Exist In File-System, Identifying If File Or Directory](http://icompile.eladkarako.com/cmd-unlimited-arguments-identifying-directory-file-or-none/)</sub>

<sub>and here is a working example that takes any amount of APK files (Android apps) and installs them on your device via debug-console (ADB.exe):
[Make The Previous Post A Mass APK Installer That Does Not Uses ADB Install-Multi Syntax](http://icompile.eladkarako.com/mass-apk-installer-wo-adb-install-multi/)</sub>

Comment: The CMD Ninja link didn't work for me, but an [archived version](https://web.archive.org/web/20160718175942/http://icompile.eladkarako.com/cmd-unlimited-arguments-identifying-directory-file-or-none/) did. Very nice summary, BTW!

Comment: You can just use :eof and then there's no need for label. It's implicit. https://ss64.com/nt/goto.html

Answer (score 16):

Get rid of the parentheses.

Sample batch file:

```
echo "%1"

if ("%1"=="") echo match1

if "%1"=="" echo match2
```

Output from running above script:

```
C:\>echo "" 
""

C:\>if ("" == "") echo match1 

C:\>if "" == "" echo match2 
match2
```

I think it is actually taking the parentheses to be part of the strings and they are being compared.

Comment: `if "%1"==""` will crash if the arg has spaces. For example: `run.bat "a b"`. @amr has the best answer to use `if "%~1"==""`

Answer (score 6):

```
IF "%~1"=="" GOTO :Usage
```

~ will de-quote %1 if %1 itself is quoted.

" " will protect from special characters passed. for example calling the script with &ping

Comment: This is the best answer. The other answers work for some cases, but will fail for more special cases like `run.bat "a b"`

Comment: @wisbucky That doesn't seem to mess up [the accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/830566/1028230). What am I missing?

Comment: @ruffin, Example: `run.bat ""` will not be caught by with `[%1]==[]`.

Answer (score 4):

This is the same as the other answers, but uses only one label and puts the usage first, which additionally makes it serve as a kind of documentation commend of the script which is also usually placed at the top:

```
@echo off
:: add other test for the arguments here...
if not [%1]==[] goto main
:: --------------------------
echo This command does something.
echo.
echo %0 param%%1 param%%2
echo       param%%1 the file to operate on
echo       param%%1 another file

:: --------------------------
exit /B 1

:main
:: --------------------------
echo do something with all arguments (%%* == %*) here...
```

However, if you don't have to use cmd/batch, use bash on WSL or powershell, they have more sane syntax and less arcane features.

Answer (score 2):

```
IF "%1"=="" GOTO :Continue
.....
.....
:Continue
IF "%1"=="" echo No Parameter given
```

Comment: This crashes for `run.bat "a b"`

Answer (score 0):

IF "%1"=="" will fail, all versions of this will fail under
certain poison character conditions.
Only IF DEFINED or IF NOT DEFINED are safe

Comment: `if [not] defined ...` doesn't work with parameters like `%1`. Do you have an example, where `if "%~1" ...` doesn't work?

Comment: Here is an easy example for code injection. Create a file called `unsafe.bat` with content ``if "%~1"=="" ( echo hello )``. Now run from Powershell the following ``.\unsafe.bat "_`" neq `"`" echo Pwned &::"``. Also run the same Powershell arguments with the community answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/34552964/1490584 . You will see that batch arguments are quite unsafe by default

Answer (score 0):

You can have a multiline if statement.  "if not defined 1" didn't work.

```
if "%1"=="" (
  echo Usage:   ApplyImage WimFileName 
  exit 1
)
```