# SHIFT doesn’t affect %*

Tags: batch-file, arguments

I’m trying to add some optional paramters to a batch file but am having trouble because the `SHIFT` command does not affect the *all-arguments* variable `%*`.

Does anyone know how I can allow for optional batch-file arguments if I have to use `%*`?

For example, a simple example that merely prints the arguments to the screen with and without a new-line, using an optional argument to determine which:

```
@echo off
if (%1)==()   goto usage
if (%1)==(/n) goto noeol
goto eol

:eol
  echo %*
  goto :eof

:noeol
  shift
  call showline %*
  goto :eof

:usage
  echo Prints text to the screen
  echo > %0 [/n] TEXT
  echo /n to NOT print a new-line at the end of the text
  goto :eof
```

Comment: I just got burned by this.  Windows SHIFT does stink.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As you know, `shift` has no effect on `%*`, but you can construct a %* equivalent.

We'll call the following `line.bat` **:**

```
@echo off
set line=%1
:loop
shift
if not "%1"=="" (
  set line=%line% %1
  goto :loop
)

echo   %%* = %*
echo line = %line%
```

If you type in the following command (Notice the double space between 3 and 4) **:**

```
line 1 2 3  4 bla dee dah
```

You will get the following output **:**

```
  %* = 1 2 3  4 bla dee dah
line = 1 2 3 4 bla dee dah
```

Note that `%*` retains multiple spaces, while using the `%n` notation does not.

---

Using something like this, you can allow your users to put their parameters in any order.

```
:loop
  :: Single variable parameters
  if "%1"=="something" set something=true
  :: Multi variable parameters 
  if "%~1"=="/source" shift & set source=%1
  shift
if not "%~1"=="" goto :loop
```

Notice that in the Multi-variable parameter statement I include one `shift` statement and one `set` statement separated by an ampersand (&). The `&` tells the command processor that a separate command to be executed follows.

---

**EDIT:**

FYI: I recommend double quotes when checking the contents of variables. **Usually** you can use **any** character, and you don't even need to use two because they are just there to insure that an empty variable does not cause an error. For instance, when `%1` is empty and you do `if not hello==%1 call :sub` the command processor will see this `if not hello== call :sub` and compare `hello` to `call` then try to execute `:sub`, and throw an error. In that specific case `if not xhello==x%1 call :sub` is just as good as `if not "hello"=="%1" call :sub`, because an empty `%1` will cause the command processor to see `if not xhello==x call :sub`.

**BUT** using characters other than double-quotes **will** cause problems if the variable contains any special characters.

Using brackets as variable delimiters like (%1) can cause problems. For instance, the (special) piping characters don't play nice inside brackets, and the escape character just seems to disappear, neither acting as a normal character, nor as the escape-character.

Also brackets are special characters in and of themselves designed to group and/or separate different lines of code and may not always act as anticipated.

Lastly, double quotes themselves are special characters **specifically designed to surround other special characters**, allowing them to act as normal characters. This is why you may see variables unquoted, then quoted again, like so.

```
set var="%~1"  & REM This sort of thing is used to insure that a variable is quoted.
                 REM %~1 unquotes %1 if it is already quoted, and leaves it alone if
                 REM %1 is not quoted.

set "var=%~1"  & REM This code assumes that `%1` contains special characters and
                 REM like before unquotes a quoted %1, but leaves the variable itself
                 REM unquoted. The double-quotes surrounding the variable and data
                 REM protects the command processor from any special characters that
                 REM exist in the data. Remember that anytime you reference `%var%`,
                 REM you will need to also surround the variable and data with
                 REM double-quotes.
```

A quick check for quotes is `if exist %1 if %1==%~1 echo Unquoted`.

Answer (score 1):

I like James’ solution because it doesn’t require anything special from the users (which is always preferable), but I just thought of another way; put the arguments in quotes and strip them at runtime:

```
Print.bat:

@echo off
if (%1)==()   goto usage
if (%1)==(/n) goto noeol
goto eol

:eol
            :: Use %~1 to 
    echo %~1
    goto :eof

:noeol
    shift
    call showline %~1
    goto :eof

:usage
    echo Prints text to the screen
    echo > %0 [/n] TEXT
    echo /n to NOT print a new-line at the end of the text
    goto :eof



Results:

    C:\>print.bat "foo bar baz"
    foo bar baz

    C:\>print.bat /n "foo bar baz"
    foo bar baz
    C:\>
```

Comment: FYI: I recommend double quotes `""`when checking the contents of variables, rather than brackets `()`. See the last edit of my answer for why.

Comment: @JamesK, I generally use parentheses for my DOS and simpler Windows batch-files because they cause less trouble for quoted arguments and have the “enclosing” sense to them. However, for compatibility and safety, it is [best to use brackets or braces](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2541767/what-is-the-proper-way-to-test-is-variable-is-empty-in-a-batch-file-if-not-1/2541820#comment17636634_2541820) since the command-interpreter does not assign any special meaning to them like it does for quotes and parentheses.