# Check if an environment variable is defined without command extensions and without using a batch file?

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

I need to use a cmd.exe command line (cmd.exe is being called from the gyp build tool) to determine whether an environment variable is defined or not.  How can I do this?  I am okay assuming that the variable value does not contain single or double quotes, but cannot assume that command extensions are enabled.

I've tried the following, which works great in a .bat file, but fails when typed directly on the command line:

```
IF "%UNDEFINED%" == "" (echo yes)
```

When that exact line is in a .bat file and executed, I see `yes` as the output.  When I type it on the command line, the output is empty.  I am testing this on Windows XP SP3, though my coworker sees the same results on Windows 7. I do not want to use `IF DEFINED UNDEFINED (echo yes)` because that won't work if command extensions are disabled. Sources for this approach:
[Microsoft KB 121170](https://web.archive.org/web/20130306082225/http://support.microsoft.com/kb/121170) [(alternate)](https://jeffpar.github.io/kbarchive/kb/121/Q121170/) and https://www.robvanderwoude.com/battech_defined.php

The top-voted answer in the following post has led me to believe that this issue is related to how percent-expansion is handled differently in the "CmdLineParser" vs. the "BatchLineParser," but still has not led me to a solution:

[How does the Windows Command Interpreter (CMD.EXE) parse scripts?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4094699/how-does-the-windows-command-interpreter-cmd-exe-parse-scripts)

Comment: At the command line you can just use the `SET` command to check if a variable is defined.

Comment: How would I use that in a conditional check?  I tried: `IF (SET UNDEFINED) (echo yes)` and got `UNDEFINED) was unexpected at this time.`

Comment: Why would you need to use the IF at the command line?  Just look at it and take the appropiate action.

Comment: The reason is that this is being used within a gyp build file, and the gyp reference says: "In a command expansion, the entire string contained within the parentheses is passed to the system’s shell." (https://code.google.com/p/gyp/wiki/InputFormatReference#Command_Expansions_(<!,_<!@)).  However, when I use the `IF "%VARIABLE%" == ""` syntax, it never evaluates to true, even when VARIABLE is not defined.  I'm assuming it's because it's running through the same command line parser. `IF DEFINED` does work as expected, but I cannot guarantee that command extensions will be enabled.

Comment: I think @RBarryYoung provided the answer. Use `set` with no args to print the environment, and use `find` to find the variable. I was going to post an answer with the same. But because of Barry's answer, it simply would have been a "me too" answer.

Comment: [What is the proper way to test if variable is empty in a batch file?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2541767/995714)

Comment: The support.microsoft.com link in this post is now dead, but luckily the Wayback Machine archived it: https://web.archive.org/web/20130306082225/http://support.microsoft.com/kb/121170 - but the edit queues are full and I can't edit it in. If anyone sees this when the queues are less full, could they please make the change? Ditto an http -> https change in the robvanderwoude URL.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

OK, this took a bit, but I think I've figured it out.  Try this:

```
SET UNDEFINED 2>Nul | Findstr/I "."
IF ERRORLEVEL 1  ECHO Not Defined.
```

This works for all cases AFAIK, and does not rely on any command extension features.

Comment: Won't work as written in this context, because the OP needs a single-line command.  I imagine you could join them up easily enough.

Comment: @HarryJohnston I see no mention of that requirement by the OP.  This meets all of the OP's stated requirements.

Comment: The gyp reference page the OP links to does not indicate any method to pass a multiple-line command to the shell.

Comment: When I wrote this question two years ago, I was careful to avoid references to `gyp`, since I didn't want to conflate issues. This answer satisfies the original question, though I never took the time to see if I could make it work with gyp. (IIRC, I took the easy way out and ended up assuming that command extensions would be enabled.)

Comment: For future reference, I believe this will also give you the wrong answer if there is a defined variable whose name begins with the name you're interested in, e.g., if you're checking whether `FOO` is defined, and there is a variable `FOOBAR` defined.

Answer (score 34):

Errr... just:

```
if defined your-var-name ( 
    echo yarp
) else (
    echo narp
)
```

I should add, I do not believe this needs command extensions...

Answer (score 10):

If the extensions are really disabled (I can't believe this),
then you can try different ways.

```
IF %UNDEFINED% == %^UNDEFINED% (echo yes)
```

This works as if `undefined` doesn't exists then it isn't replaced, also `^undefined` but the caret will be removed in the next parser phase, so `%undefined%` is compared against `%undefined%`.
The disadvantage are the missing quotes, as they also make the expression stable against special characters.

A better way is to use `IF defined`, but when extensions are disabled you need to enable them first.

```
cmd /E:on /c "if not defined undefined echo It's undefined"
```

The best way is to simply use a batch file, that should also work with gyp build system.

Comment: excelent solution... the best for the case... great idea to force a literal... THX!

Answer (score 5):

I tried this and it worked:

```
@echo off

setlocal disableextensions

set x=%path%
if "%x%"=="" (echo "PATH" does not exist) else (echo "PATH" exists)

set x=%pathx%
if "%x%"=="" (echo "PATHX" does not exist) else (echo "PATHX" exists)

endlocal
```

It returned:

```
"PATH" exists
"PATHX" does not exist
```

Comment: I got: ```"PATH" exists``` ```"PATHX" exists```.  Any idea why that might be?

Comment: What OS are you using?  You might add `set x=` between the two sections just to be sure that `x` is undefined before the 2nd instance...  Unless you have a `pathx` environment variable!  Have you typed `set pathx` to see?

Comment: Adding `set x=` between the sections didn't change it.  I still get `"PATH" exists` `"PATHX" exists` on both Windows XP SP3, and two different Windows 7 SP1 machines.

Comment: Works fine for me.  Try leaving echo on to see what's happening.

Comment: But it will not work on the command line, only in a batch file

Comment: @jeb: looks like James and I both misinterpreted the question!

Answer (score 1):

```
IF NOT %CODE%==? do stuff.
```

This works on a W98 command line and in a batch file, so it ought to work anywhere from early MS-DOS onwards with no extensions needed. It assumes that CODE is usefully set or not set at all.

It results in a syntax error if CODE does not exist, or does nothing if CODE is a question mark (chosen because it could never exist in a path). Either way, nothing is done. The NOT makes sure action is only taken if CODE appears to be set to something useful.

I use it in compiler batch files to determine whether to use relative paths or use a fixed base directory if one is set in the CODE variable. It allows me to make a coding tree portable without having to modify all the batch files for each program if I move everything.