# How to check if a variable exists in a batch file?

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

I am using the `call` command:

```
call beingcalled.bat randomnumber
```

In **beingcalled.bat**:

```
@echo off
set call=%1
echo %call%
set call=%call%%call%
call caller.bat %call%`
```

In **caller.bat**:

```
@echo off
set calltwo=%1
echo %calltwo%
if "%calltwo%"== "" (
    echo Error
) else (
    call beingcalled.bat randomnumber
)
```

Why does the command `if "%calltwo%"== ""` not work? And how do I see if a variable was set?

Comment: What about `if defined calltwo`?

Comment: your `if` _is_ working, but the variable is never empty - you successfully built an endless loop and finally will get an errormessage (recursion depth overflow).

Comment: There is a crucial difference in your need between "test if is set (exists)" and "test if the value is not empty"

Answer (score 64, accepted):

```
IF "%Variable%"=="" ECHO Variable is NOT defined
```

This should help but this works, provided the value of Variable does not contain double quotes.
Or you may try. Both worked for me.

```
VERIFY OTHER 2>nul
SETLOCAL ENABLEEXTENSIONS
IF ERRORLEVEL 1 ECHO Unable to enable extensions
IF DEFINED MyVar (ECHO MyVar IS defined) ELSE (ECHO MyVar is NOT defined)
ENDLOCAL
```

> source https://www.robvanderwoude.com/battech_defined.php

Comment: Why did you open a bounty for a question that you have the accepted answer to? If you think your answer could be improved, just update it.

Comment: I opened the bounty hoping someone would give a better answer. My answer although works Im searching for something more efficient and simply better answer.

Comment: The `if defined` answer that both you and K4dse posted is the method that is considered best practice (although the first three lines of your second answer are unnecessary).

Comment: May I use a pattern of variable names? So if I know it starts with `ICPP...` Can I use something like `ICPP*`?

Comment: `IF "%wefgejroigejrmghuiohrbtg%"=="" ECHO Variable is NOT defined` does not output anything for me on Windows 10 20H2. Obviously, that variable is not defined.

Comment: Does this work with command-line arguments? On Win 10, this returns "NOT defined", even if arg 3 was passed to the script: `IF DEFINED %3 (ECHO defined) ELSE (ECHO NOT defined)`

Comment: Comparison does not work for me too on Windows 10, and I see when I do `echo %NO_VAR_WITH_THIS_NAME%` it echoes `%NO_VAR_WITH_THIS_NAME%`, not an empty string. However `if defined` does properly the job.

Comment: If anyone reading this has the rep for a 1-character edit, there is now an https version of the URL linked to in this question.

Answer (score 50):

The easiest way is just using the command line extension DEFINED. This is also my preferred way of doing this.

in your case:

```
@echo off
set calltwo=%1
echo %calltwo%
if defined calltwo (
echo Error
)else (
call beingcalled.bat randomnumber
)
```

If this doesn't work for you there is a workaround in the link below.

The question is also a duplicate of: [Check if an environment variable is defined without command extensions and without using a batch file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16367814/check-if-an-environment-variable-is-defined-without-command-extensions-and-witho)

Answer (score 6):

None of these solutions work for me on windows 10, but I did find a solution that does work

```
IF %foo%==^%foo^% ECHO variable not defined
```

Comment: this works on command line, but not in batch file. %foo% is replaced differently in these cases

Answer (score 5):

This is just a follow-up to the comment (and bounty) post by @Rishav

Here’s a trick I picked up a very long time ago:

```
@ECHO OFF

SET Foo=%1

ECHO ==  Start  ====================

ECHO %Foo%

IF %Foo%x == x ECHO Parameter not set

ECHO ==  End  ====================
ECHO.
```

If the parameter is not set, you get a check of `x==x`

If the parameter is set (to, say, “asdf”), you get a check of `asdfx==x`

Comment: gives you an Syntax error, when the variable happens to have a space. Only secure way is using quotes `IF "%Variable%"==""` (like accepted answer)

Comment: Even `IF "%Variable%"==""` is not secure and can result in a exit of batch processing because of a syntax error or doing something complete different than batch file is designed for depending on value of `Variable`.  Example: `Variable` has the value `" == "" call dir %USERPROFILE% & pause & rem "`. Secure is only enabling delayed expansion and using `IF "!Variable!" == ""` as in this case the value of environment variable `Variable` does not modify the __IF__ command line finally executed by `cmd.exe` after preprocessing it.