# How can I trap an ENTER keystroke in batch?

Tags: batch-file

New to the site and to scripting in general. I am aware that you can create user inputs like this:

```
set input=
set /p input=[y/n]: %=%
```

then you can ask using "if" to see if they are certain responses. Example:

```
if "%input%"=="y" goto a:
```

and check if it isn't said input by saying

```
if "%input%" NEQ "y" goto b:
```

Because I'm uneducated, I don't know how to accomplish this, but I want to be able to determine if the input was an enter keystroke.
I have tried to accomplish this by using

```
if "%input%"==[ENTER] goto a:
```

and

```
if "%input%"==enter
```

and every method I could think of to determine if the keystroke was an [ENTER]. I am probably just stupid, but is there a way to do this? Thanks.

Comment: If they just hit enter the string will be blank, provided that it was blank before the set command: `if "%input%"==""`

Comment: You should realize that the ENTER key is _always_ pressed in order to end a `set /P` command, so your entire description is confusing. I suggest you to change the topic title to "How to detect an empty input in SET /P command" and modify the description accordingly...

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27489804/set-p-empty-answer-crash

Answer (score 5):

There are at least two ways to do that: check the value or check the operation

`set /p` retrieves the typed input storing it inside a variable, but when there is no input, just an <kbd>Enter</kbd> press, there is no storage operation on the variable so it keeps its previous value.

The usual way to test the value is to clear the variable contents, use the `set /p` and test if the variable is defined, that is, it has content

```dos
set "var="
set /p "var=[y/n]?"
if not defined var goto :noUserInput
```

We can also test the operation itself. In batch files most of the commands set to some value the internal `errorlevel` variable indicating the sucess or failure of the execution of the command.

In the case of the `set /p` it will set `errorlevel` to 0 if data has been retrieved and will set it to 1 if there is no input. Then the `if errorlevel` construct can be used to determine if there was input

```dos
set /p "var=[y/n]?"
if errorlevel 1 goto :noUserInput
```

As Aacini points, this can fail. If the batch file has `.bat` extension a `set /p` that reads data will not reset (set to 0) a previous `errorlevel` value, so it is necessary to first execute some command to set the `errorlevel` to 0.

```dos
ver > nul
set /p "var=[y/n]?"
if errorlevel 1 goto :noUserInput
```

If the batch file is saved with `.cmd` extension this is not needed. In this case the `set /p` will set the `errorlevel` to 0 when it reads data.

Also conditional execution operators (`&&` and `||`) can be used. `&&` executes the next command if the previous one was sucessful. `||` will execute the next command if the previous one failed.

```dos
set /p "var=[y/n]?" || goto :noUserInput
```

Comment: Just a detail here: when `set /P` command reads input it does _NOT_ modify the previous value of errorlevel, so you need to be sure that the errorlevel is zero before the `set /P`. A simple way of do that is with VER command: `ver > NUL`  `set /P var=`  `if errorlevel 1 goto noInput`

Comment: @Aacini, I used to think so, but before posting the answer I tested it (XP SP3, what I had at hand) from a batch file (`echo test | find "x"`, `set /p data=`, `echo %errorlevel%`) and it works as indicated in the answer. BUT, as you point,  from command line `set /p` does not clear (set to 0) the errorlevel.

Comment: @Aacini, well to be precise, I tested it from a batch file with `.cmd` instance. If executed from a file with `.bat` extension then `set /p` does not reset the `errorlevel`. In this scenario you are right.

Comment: @Aacini, now included in the answer. Thank you.

Comment: Yes: if the Batch file have `.bat` extension the errorlevel is _not_ changed. It is changed when the Batch file have `.cmd` extension! Tested on Win 8.1

Answer (score 1):

```
If not defined input ...
```

detects whether `input` has an assigned value.

Coding

```
set "input="
set /p "input=[y/n]: "
if not defined input echo Enter alone detected
```

should detect the enter key alone being operated.

The syntax `set "var=string"` ensures that trailing spaces on the line are not included in the value assigned (they're hard to see).

Note that a response of simply <kbd>Enter</kbd> will leave the target variable unchanged; it will not assign *nothing* to the variable. For this reason, it is wise to ensure that the variable is cleared before a manual entry.