# error: call was unexpected at this time when i use call command behind if judgment

Tags: batch-file, cmd

I'm newer in bat command and learning .i meet a issue and i can't fix it .
it caused a error that "call" was unexpected at this time when i invoke call command behind if judgment.my bat files are below.
I ask everyone for help to solve it.thx very much. pls

test1.bat

```
@echo off
echo test1.bat running
set value=%1
set param=t1

if %errorlevel%==0 goto:dif

:dif
if %value%==%param% call test2.bat

pause
```

test2.bat

```
@echo off

echo test2.bat running
```

it will nothing when i input *test1 t1*, but the error occur as i input *test1* command line in cmd .

---

Ok,I change the question and update test1.bat file now.

test1.bat

```
@echo off
echo test1.bat running
set "value=t1"

if  "%value%==-t1"  call "test2.bat"
if  "%value%==t1"   echo ok
```

There is the same error occured when i input **test1** command line.

Error:*call was unexpected at this time*

I want to know why cause this error.

Comment: Are you expecting that `t1==!t1!`? because clearly it doesn't!

Comment: [possible duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27489804/2152082) (in spite of the misleading title)

Comment: sorry for that,it should be show as %value%==%param%,i forget delete the 
exclamatory mark..

Comment: @SnailMann Are you wanting to match part of %1, so you want to match `t1` in `test1`?

Comment: @GerhardBarnard Yes,i want to run function dif if i input test t1 in cmd.Just %1(the second paraments) match t1 successful.

Comment: Ok, that will not work then. let me edit my answer.

Comment: @GerhardBarnard Ok,thx for you help~

Comment: ok, see edit in my answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a quick example of the pertinent lines from your provided scripts:

**test1.bat**

```bat
@Echo Off
Echo %~nx0 running
Set "value=%~1"
Set "param=t1"
If /I "%value%"=="%param%" Call "test2.bat"
Pause
```

**test2.bat**

```bat
@Echo Off
Echo %~nx0 running
```

It should show you how to reference the script name dynamically, how to use doublequotes as best practice to protect values or strings and how to do conditional verification using `If`.

*For information on a command, just enter `CommandName /?` at the Command prompt; i.e. `Set /?`, `If /?` or `Call /?`*

Comment: This will only match If full string of `%1` is `t1` and will not match `test1`

Comment: @Gerhard, my reading is that the OP enters `test1 t1` this runs `test1.bat` with the parameter, `t1` as `%1`. They reported an error when they input `test1`, because they ran `test1.bat` with no parameter. Their code therefore `undefined` the variable `%value%` meaning that `if ==!%param%! call test2.bat` was trying to run.

Comment: Yeah I asked him to clarify now, I am pretty focussed on the last line where he states in the last line _"but the error occur as i input test1 command in cmd"_ so I am also just assuming he wants to match `t1` in `test1` :)

Comment: So we are both almost correct, he wants to match `%2` with `t1` so you can update answer.

Comment: Yes they input the command `test1` in cmd.exe, previous to that they input `test1 t1`. Because `.bat` is included in `%PATHEXT%` it will be run without having to use its extension, otherwise their commands at the Command prompt would have been `test1.cmd t1` and `test1.cmd`

Comment: @Compo Thanks,It working !But i want to ask you some question too.What is the different between if /t and if? and what is the effects of useing doubleequotes？pls

Comment: ok, I think I got confused with the English usage with OP, so I should rather delete answer.

Comment: @SnailMann, use the `IF /?` as mentioned in my answer, it isn't the letter `t` it is a capitalized letter `i`, which does a case insensitive check meaning that `t1` and `T1` will match!

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear what you are inputting.

If you execute the command `test1 t1`

then:

`value` will acquire the value `t1` (from the command-line tail)
`param` will acquire the value `t1` 
`errorlevel` will be set to `0` as the `set` was successful, so

```
if %errorlevel%==0 goto:dif
```

will go to `:dif` as the *contents* of `errorlevel` (`%errorlevel%`) is `0` and `0==0`

There is a small difficulty here, since if `errorlevel` was *not* `0`, then the `if` condition would *not* execute `goto dif` (the colon is better omitted) so the procedure will continue - to the label `:dif` in any case...

```
if %value%==!%param%! call test2.bat
```

will be evaluated by substitution of the *current* values and execute

```
if t1==!t1! call test2.bat
```

since both `value` and `param` contain `t1`.
BUT `t1` is *not* equal to `!t1!`, so the `call` instruction will be ignored.

---

If you execute the command `test1`

`value` will acquire the value *nothing* (since there is no command-line tail)
`param` will acquire the value `t1` 
`errorlevel` will be set to `0` as the `set` was successful, so

```
if %errorlevel%==0 goto:dif
```

will go to `:dif` as the *contents* of `errorlevel` (`%errorlevel%`) is `0` and `0==0`

```
if %value%==!%param%! call test2.bat
```

will be evaluated by substitution of the *current* values and execute

```
if ==!t1! call test2.bat
```

since `value` contains *nothing* and `param` contains `t1`.

This is a syntax error because `cmd` expects

`if string1==string2 ...`

---

The other issue is the use of `!something!`.

Normally, `!` is just another character, like `x` or `q` in batch, and `%var%` means `the content of the variable "var"`.

When you have a *code block* ( a series of commands within parentheses) then batch first substitutes the value of `var` for `%var%` and then executes the command, so

```
set "var=original"
for %%a in (1 2 3) do (
  rem this is a code block
  echo before %var%
  set "var=modified"
  echo after  %var%
)
echo then  %var%
```

will report `original`, `original` 3 times and `modified` because what is actually executed is

```
set "var=original"
for %%a in (1 2 3) do (
  rem this is a code block
  echo before original
  set "var=modified"
  echo after  original
)
echo then  %var%
```

This changes when the special command

```
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
```

is executed. `!` then acquires a special meaning.

```
set "var=original"
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
for %%a in (1 2 3) do (
  rem this is a code block
  echo before %var% !var! 
  set "var=modified"
  echo after  %var% !var!
)
echo then  %var% !var!
endlocal
echo final %var% !var!
```

In this case, the report will be

> before original original
>   after  original modified
>   before original modified
>   after  original modified
>   before original modified
>   after  original modified
>   then   modified modified
>   final  original !var!

because `%var%` refers to the *original* value, and `!var!` to the *modified* value (hence at the very first `before`, the variable has not yet been modified, but at the `after`, the variable *has* been modified, so the second and third loops report the *modified* value as `!var!`)

After the loop, both `%var%` and `!var!` report the same thing (the value was mofified within the loop, but not *after* the end of the loop).

And finally, the `endlocal` turns the `delayedexpansion` off, so the `!` becomes a normal character again, and `endlocal` also throws away any modifications made to the variables after the `setlocal` was executed. Hence the original value of `var` is shown (as it was when the `setlocal` was executed) and `!var!` is no longer a special string.

So - your

```
if %value%==!%param%! call test2.bat
```

would, **if `setlocal enabledelayedexpansion` had been executed** and `param` contains `t1` actually execute

`if the value contained in "value"==the value contained in "t1" call test2.bat`

Comment: Ok!Thanks for your detail answers,and i got your mean about how to use "setlocal enabledelayedexpansion" command and  "!". Thanks.But i want to know why it will report that call was unexpected at this time when i input test1 command line in cmd.exe.Pls ingore ! symbol.

Comment: It's not clear what your *actual* command-entry is. If all you are entering is "test1" then read the second block above, starting `If you execute the command test1` where I've shown what happens step-by-step. Please note that in comments you can change to *italics* using a single asterisk at the beginning and end of the text you want to hilight and **if you use two asterisks then you will get BOLD text**

Comment: Ok, I update my question now and the explanation is clearer.pls help to check it and find the casue.thx

Comment: Fine. Now we are certain what is being entered. :) So - please re-read my response, in the second section which starts "If you execute the command `test1`" and ignore the `!` characters as they have now been removed and the saga about `delayedexpansion` is now not relevant.