# This code does not run but only exits. I am not sure where I have made a mistake

Tags: batch-file

I am hoping you can help me. So, I have been trying to run this command. But everytime I do so..it exits out. Then, I found this error.."batch file do( was unexpected at this time" I am not sure where I made a mistake. Thanks in advance for all the replies.

Here is my code:

```
@echo off
for /L %%n in (1,1,3) do (
    set uname=mama 
    set pword=mu

    :xy
    set /p user ="Enter Username"
    set /p pass="Enter Pass"
    if %uname%==%user% ( echo 
        username is valid ) ELSE (
        echo username not found
        goto xy
    )
    IF %pword%==%pass% ( echo sucess 
    ) ELSE (
        echo invalid password
        goto xy
    )
    pause
    if %%n EQU 3 (echo Run Again)
)
```

Comment: no labels and no `goto`s allowed within a code block. Change your logic. Technically: [delayed expansion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30282784/variables-are-not-behaving-as-expected/30284028#30284028) in combination with [empty variable with if](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27489804/set-p-empty-answer-crash/27489844#27489844)

Answer (score 0):

This is elaborated based in **[@Stephan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2152082/stephan)** comments:

Replace the **`for`** loop with a **`_cnt`** counter to limit attempts by **`if`**.

---

```bat
@echo off && setlocal enabledelayedexpansion 

set "uname=mama" && set "pword=mu"

:xy

set /a "_cnt+=1+0" && set /p "user=Enter Username: "

if not !_cnt! EQU 3 (

   if "!uname!" == "!user!" (echo/ Username is valid^!! 
       ) else ( echo/ Username not found^!! & goto :xy )

   set /p "pass=Enter Pass: " 

   if "!pword!" == "!pass!" (echo/ Sucess^!! 
       ) else ( echo/ Invalid password^!! & goto :xy )

   ) else ( echo/ Run Again^!! && %__APPDIR__%timeout -1 & endlocal &  goto :EOF )

rem./ do more tasks here... after use endlocal ... && endlocal & goto :EOFF
```

---

Answer (score 0):

Looking at your code it appeared to me that using `Call` would solve both your nested label and delayed expansion issues, *and probably make your code easier for you to manage*.

```bat
@Echo Off
Set "uname=mama"
Set "pword=mu"
Set "user="
Set "pass="

:Inputs
For /L %%G In (1,1,3) Do (
    Call :xy
    If Not ErrorLevel 1 GoTo Main
)
"%__AppDir__%choice.exe" /M "Would you like to try again"
If Not ErrorLevel 2 GoTo Inputs
Exit /B 1

:Main
Rem Your code below here for users with successful inputs.
Echo Welcome %user%.
Timeout /T 3 /NoBreak > NUL
Rem Your code ends above here.
Exit /B 0

:xy
ClS
Set /P "user=Enter Username> %user%"
If /I Not "%uname%" == "%user%" (
    Echo Username not found.
    Set "user="
    Timeout /T 2 /NoBreak > NUL
    Exit /B 1
)
Echo Username is valid.
Set /P "pass=Enter Pass> "
IF "%pword%" == "%pass%" Exit /B 0
Echo Invalid password.
Set "pass="
Timeout /T 2 /NoBreak > NUL
Exit /B 1
```

You may notice that I've used the recommended syntax for defining variables with the `Set` command. It ensures that the content is protected and does not have things such as hidden trailing spaces. If you take a look at the code in your question, you will note that the value assigned to the `uname` variable is actually `mama<space>`. This would obviously cause issues when `mama` is locked out of the rest of the script!

*You also notice had an unwanted newline instead of a space between `echo` and `username is valid`.*

**Edit**

The code above was re-worked to allow for up to three attempts at entering both values correctly, *although the `try again` message seems a little redundant then*.

Comment: that forces the user to enter valid credentials three times before executing the payload.

Comment: To be honest with you @Stephan, I didn't even consider that the intention was to allow the end user only three attempts at getting both entries correct. I apologise for my misunderstanding and have re-worked my code to account for that.

Answer (score 0):

You had a few errors in your code.

1. labels are not allowed in code blocks and may break them. // Labels removed.
2. `goto` unconditionally breaks the code block // left one `goto` to intentionally leave the loop and removed the rest
3. you need [delayed expansion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30282784/variables-are-not-behaving-as-expected/30284028#30284028) to use a variable changed within the same code block (technically not needed for `uname` and `pword`, as I defined them outside the loop) // enabled and used delayed expansion
4. You had a space in `set uname=mama<space>` // fixed by recommended syntax `set "var=value"`
5. (security issue) for security reasons, you shouldn't tell if it was the username or the password (or both), which was wrong. // fixed (as a bonus, it simplifies the code)

With the above errors fixed and reduced code complexity, it could look like:

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
set "uname=mama"
set "pword=mu"
for /L %%n in (1,1,3) do (
    set /p "user=Enter Username: "
    set /p "pass=Enter Password: "
    if "!uname!-!pword!" == "!user!-!pass!" goto :payload
    echo Invalid username or password.
    pause
)
echo sorry, run again.
goto :eof

:payload
echo successfully logged in.
REM rest of your code
```

(speaking of security: having the credentials in clear text in the (readable) code isn't secure by any standard, but it's hard to overcome with pure batch)