# Trying to make an menu that dosnt crash when type nothing but press enter

Tags: batch-file

I am trying to make a menu but it doesn't close the program if you type nothing then press enter it will go to the menu again and you can try again with a number that works

```
:menu
echo.
echo 1- Tools
echo 2- Setting
echo 3- Games
echo 4- Info
echo x- Exit
set /p menu=?
if %menu%==1 (
goto tool
) else (
if %menu%==2 (
goto settings
) else (
if %menu%==3 (
goto game
) else (
if %menu%==4 (
goto info
) else (
if %menu%==x )
goto exits
) else (
goto menu

:tool
title tools by gloxidia
pause
:settings
title settings by gloxidia
pause
:game
title game by gloxidia
pause
:exits
title exit by gloxidia
exit
```

I can't get it to work in my program I am working on

Comment: at the moment it just crashes when you type eny number then press enter

Comment: Does this answer your question? [set /p empty answer crash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27489804/set-p-empty-answer-crash)

Comment: This would be a good time to use `Choice` doing so will allow you to limit the responces to only those presented as acceptable answers, Check out the options `choice /?`

Answer (score 2):

The daily "menu" question.

Two items with your code as it stands:

1. If you use parenthesised code (`code blocks`) in an `if` statement, then each `(` must be balanced by a `)`. You have many more `(` than `)` so your `if` statement will fail as it is invalid syntax.
2. If you press just <kbd>Enter</kbd> then the variable (in this case, `menu`) remains **unchanged**, it is not automatically `set` to *nothing*.

It's very possible that `menu` will in fact be empty when you start the batch, but to make sure, put

```
set "menu="
```

before the `set /p` statement.

BUT the downside of this is that if `menu` is empty when the `if` is processed, for instance,

```
if %menu%==2 (
```

will be interpreted as

```
if ==2 (
```

which is invalid syntax.

The classic cure, generally, is to code

```
if "%menu%"=="2" (
```

where the quotes are both included in the comparison and partially-sanitise the input so that a value that contains spaces will now be correctly interpreted.

BUT (again) there are problems. The input is uncontrolled, so you could enter `"hello"` or `hello` or `%hello%` or `he"llo`, which will all cause problems with the `if` statement, even if the `if "%menu%"=="2"` syntax is used.

Hence, the solution is to use `choice` - there are many examples available on SO - just use the `search` facility.

Also please consider your code structure and logic. A long cascaded `if/then` sequence is a nightmare.

Consider

```
if "%menu%"=="2" (goto somewhere)
rem MENU must be "not 2" to reach here
if "%menu%"=="3" (goto somewhereelse)
rem MENU must be "neither 2 nor 3" to reach here
if "%menu%"=="4" (goto somewhereelseagain)
rem MENU must be "neither 2,3 nor 4" to reach here
```

But really, you're far better off with `choice`.

Answer (score 0):

The main problem, is with all of your unnecessary `if` / `else` blocks. I added some indentation to hopefully more clearly show you what's happening, but essentially you opened many parentheses without closing them.

```batch-file
:Menu
Set "MenuItem="
Echo=
Echo 1- Tools
Echo 2- Setting
Echo 3- Games
Echo 4- Info
Echo X- Exit
Set /P "MenuItem=?"
If "%MenuItem%" == "1" (
    GoTo Tools
) Else (
    If "%MenuItem%" == "2" (
        GoTo Settings
    ) Else (
        If "%MenuItem%" == "3" (
            GoTo Games
        ) Else (
            If "%MenuItem%" == "4" (
                GoTo Info
            ) Else (
                If /I "%MenuItem%" == "X" (
                    GoTo Exits
                ) Else (
                    GoTo Menu
                )
            )
        )
    )
)

:Tools
Title Tools by Gloxidia
Pause
GoTo Exits

:Settings
Title Settings by Gloxidia
Pause
GoTo Exits

:Games
Title Games by Gloxidia
Pause
GoTo Exits

:Info
Title Info by Gloxidia
Pause

:Exits
Title Exits by Gloxidia
Pause
Exit /B
```

To help protect the variable, with regards some poison characters and empty input, I've added doublequotes on either side of the `If` comparison. Additionally in order to prevent the code from cycling through all remaining commands and `exit`ing before you've had time to notice it, I've added some `GoTo` commands, and changed `Exit` to `Exit /B`.

Here it is with again without the unnecessary `If` / `Else` command blocks.

```batch-file
:Menu
Set "MenuItem="
Echo=
Echo 1. Tools
Echo 2. Settings
Echo 3. Games
Echo 4. Info
Echo X. Exit
Set /P "MenuItem=?"
If "%MenuItem%" == "1" GoTo Tools
If "%MenuItem%" == "2" GoTo Settings
If "%MenuItem%" == "3" GoTo Games
If "%MenuItem%" == "4" GoTo Info
If /I "%MenuItem%" == "X" GoTo Exits
GoTo Menu

:Tools
Title Tools by Gloxidia
Pause
GoTo Exits

:Settings
Title Settings by Gloxidia
Pause
GoTo Exits

:Games
Title Games by Gloxidia
Pause
GoTo Exits

:Info
Title Info by Gloxidia
Pause

:Exits
Title Exits by Gloxidia
Pause
Exit /B
```

The biggest issue, with the above code, is that it is using the wrong command, `set /p` is not the correct command to use for accepting known single character input from a short list.

What you should be using is the `choice` command utility:

```batch-file
:Menu
Echo=
Echo 1. Tools
Echo 2. Settings
Echo 3. Games
Echo 4. Info
Echo X. Exit
%SystemRoot%\System32\choice.exe /C 1234X
If ErrorLevel 5 GoTo Exits
If ErrorLevel 4 GoTo Info
If ErrorLevel 3 GoTo Games
If ErrorLevel 2 GoTo Settings

:Tools
Title Tools by Gloxidia
Pause
GoTo Exits

:Settings
Title Settings by Gloxidia
Pause
GoTo Exits

:Games
Title Games by Gloxidia
Pause
GoTo Exits

:Info
Title Info by Gloxidia
Pause

:Exits
Title Exits by Gloxidia
Pause
Exit /B
```

Answer (score 0):

The exact answer to your question is that you use `else (` but never close the parenthesis.

You could just fix rhis but I suggest you follow some of the advice in this q and others.

To simply fix your existing batch script:

```
umber that works

:menu
 echo.
 echo 1- Tools
 echo 2- Setting
 echo 3- Games
 echo 4- Info
 echo x- Exit
set /p "menu=?"
if "%menu%" EQU "1" ( goto :tool ) else (
  if "%menu%" EQU "2" ( goto :settings ) else (
    if "%menu%" EQU "3" ( goto :game ) else (
      if "%menu%" EQU "4" ( goto :info ) else (
        if /I "%menu%" EQU "x" ( goto :exits )
      )
    )
  )
)

Goto :Menu

:tool
  title tools by gloxidia
  pause
Goto :eof

:settings
  title settings by gloxidia
  pause
Goto :eof

:game
  title game by gloxidia
  pause
Goto :eof

:exits
  title exit by gloxidia
  Echo=I can't get it to work
  Pause
Goto :eof
```

Alternatives:

You could forgo the `GOTO :label` portion and write your code insise the nested if statements

Probably you have rhem for a good reason though, so:

You could simply call the labels directly and ignore the bested IF making it much more streamlined.

This is rhat streamlined alternative

```
UGH even my edits saying I'm annoyed seem to have screwed up, its very late and I am on mobile, I just need to relax and not spend all night qriting this
```