# Something wrong with my IF statement in Batch

Tags: batch-file, cmd

Heres a simplified version of what I'm after:

```
SET outFile=
IF "%outFile%"=="" (
    echo Output file=[Console]
    SET outFile=CON
) ELSE ( 
    IF "%outFile:~0,3%"=="%HOMEDRIVE%\" (
        echo Output file=%outFile%
        SET outFile=%outFile%
    ) ELSE ( 
        echo Output file=%cd%\%outFile%
        SET outFile=%cd%\%outFile%  
    )
)
```

It works in all conditions except for outFile being empty which returns the error "( was unexpected at this time."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add `setlocal enabledelayedexpansion` in your batch, and use `!outFile:~0,3!` inside your second IF, like below:

```
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

IF "%outFile%"=="" (
    echo Output file=[Console]
    SET outFile=CON
) ELSE ( 
    IF "!outFile:~0,3!"=="%HOMEDRIVE%\" (
        echo Output file=%outFile%
        SET outFile=%outFile%
    ) ELSE ( 
        echo Output file=%cd%\%outFile%
        SET outFile=%cd%\%outFile%  
    )
)
```

Furthermore, you could take a look at this thread to get more info about [What is the proper way to test if variable is empty in a batch file?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2541767/4584335)