# .sh to .bat files converting

Tags: windows, shell, batch-file, command

I need to convert a .sh file to a .bat file but don't know the right syntax. I already done some translations I've found but I'm not really sure about all sh syntax. Very thanks for all advices you can give to me.

Here is what I've done so far :

```
setlocal
rem!\bin\bat`enter code here`


    rem *****************************************************
    rem * Setting up the JBOSS local variables
    rem *****************************************************

    if [ "x%PROJECT_DIR%" = "x" ]; then
        DIRNAME=`dirname $0`
        PWD="$( cd -P "$DIRNAME" && pwd )"
        SET PROJECT_DIR="$( cd -P "$PWD" && pwd )"
    fi
    SET JBOSS_DIR=%PROJECT_DIR%\..\..\nqi\4.3\nqi\orchestra\jboss
    SET SERVER_HOME_DIR=$JBOSS_DIR\orchestra
    SET PORTFOLIO_CONFIG=%PROJECT_DIR%\..\..\nqi\4.3\nqi\orchestra\applications\custom\portfolio
    rem *****************************************************


    echo "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX"
    echo ""
    echo "DIRNAME = %DIRNAME%"
    echo "PROJECT_DIR = %PROJECT_DIR%"
    echo "SERVER_HOME_DIR = %SERVER_HOME_DIR%"
    echo ""
    echo "  nqidb-ds.xml deployement"
    rm -f %SERVER_HOME_DIR%\deploy\nqidb-ds.xml
    cp -Tfv %PROJECT_DIR%\dev_stuff\nqidb-ds.xml %SERVER_HOME_DIR%\deploy\nqidb-ds.xml

    echo ""
    echo "  ui properties deployement"
    rm -rf %PROJECT_DIR%\applications\local
    mkdir %PROJECT_DIR%\applications\local
    mkdir %PROJECT_DIR%\applications\local\nqi-ui
    cp -Tfv %PROJECT_DIR%\dev_stuff\nqi-ui.properties %PROJECT_DIR%\applications\local\nqi-ui\nqi-ui.properties

    echo ""
    echo "  workflow deployement"
    mkdir %PROJECT_DIR%\applications\local\workflow
    cp -Tfv %PROJECT_DIR%\dev_stuff\workflow-config.xml %PROJECT_DIR%\applications\local\workflow\workflow-config.xml

    echo ""
    echo "  license deployement"
    mkdir %PROJECT_DIR%\applications\local\license
    cp -Tfv %PROJECT_DIR%\dev_stuff\nqi.license %PROJECT_DIR%\applications\local\license\nqi.license

    echo ""
    echo "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX"
    echo ""
    echo "  JBoss Starting..."
    %JBOSS_DIR%\bin\run.bat endlocal
```

Comment: For `if [ "x%PROJECT_DIR%" = "x" ]; then` try a look at [What is the proper way to test if variable is empty in a batch...](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2541767/what-is-the-proper-way-to-test-if-variable-is-empty-in-a-batch-file-if-not-1)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because Stack Overflow is not a code rewriting service.

Comment: Type `help` at the cmd prompt to see a list of commands you can use. To get help for a particular command you can type `help if` or `if /?`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unfortunately this is a case where you just have to try & test until you get it right.

You are on the right track, and i dont think any advise you will get here will speed up the process much.

Identify the command in the sh file, google it for the bat equivalent syntax, add that to your new file and test. once you are sure that portion works as expected in your environment, move on to the next line.

As these files are "mostly" linear, read from top to bottom, it makes testing each line quite a bit easier.

Comment: Ok thanks to you for you answer ;)