# Two sets of double quotes batch file error

Tags: batch-file, double-quotes

Why does the following batch script fail?
Is it because there are 2 sets of double quotes?
How do I get this to work??

```
SET INCOME-CODE="test (bob, bob2)"

IF "%INCOME-CODE%"=="NULL" (

  SET APCINVOICE=%APCINVOICE%,

 ) ELSE (

   SET APCINVOICE=%APCINVOICE%%INCOME-CODE%,

 )
```

Comment: Do you want to check if `INCOME-CODE` is defined?

Comment: Are you sure hyphens for variable names are allowed in batch files?

Comment: What do you mean by fail?  The code definitely does not cause a failure.  But yes, your string comparison will not work if your string has quotes and your then put quotes around the variable for the comparison.

Comment: @DanielAlder the hyphen seems to be valid. The problem is indeed the presence of two consecutive quotation marks, as the OP suspected. This turns the IF statement to `IF ""test (bob, bob2)"" and because there are two quotes, the string is actually taken as three separate words.

Comment: Hyphens are working fine in other variable names. By fail I mean the batch file just stop running.

Comment: Usually Incomde-Code comes in with no value but is shows as null, we are checking to see if there is a value there

Comment: @venatic if **INCOME-CODE** shows as null then it has a value.  In batch if there is no value assigned to a variable then it becomes undefined. Essentially the variable does not exist.

Comment: Use `SET "INCOME-CODE=test (bob, bob2)"` instead of `SET INCOME-CODE="test (bob, bob2)"`, so the `""` do not become part of the variable value; then the comparison should work...

Comment: @Squashman it failed for me... `(bob was unexpected at this time.`

Answer (score 0):

Two things.

**First**, your variable `INCOME-CODE` actually has quotes in it.  Try this short demonstration:

```
@echo off
set TEST1="this is a string with spaces"
set "TEST2=this is a string with spaces"
echo %TEST1%
echo %TEST2%
```

**Second**, you are comparing to the literal string "NULL".  There is no NULL value in batch.  Please see this post for more details: [What is the proper way to test if variable is empty in a batch file...](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2541767/what-is-the-proper-way-to-test-if-variable-is-empty-in-a-batch-file-if-not-1)  What you probably want to do is compare to an empty string or use one of the methods in the question above if you're working with something more complex.

```
IF "%INCOME-CODE%"=="" ( ... )
```