# Stop function running after being cancelled - Batch file

Tags: batch-file, vbscript

I'm trying to run a script that prompts a user for a location and once that location has been selected, the script will copy IE favorites to that location .(It's part of a bigger project to copy multiple directories to a location of your choice)

It starts off with a VBS script to create the prompt, then I create a variable based on what's selected. Then the script copies IE favorites to that selected location. The problem is, if I select "cancel" the script runs anyway!

Any help is much appreciated!

Code: (Batch Script)

```
@echo off

For /F "Tokens=1 Delims=" %%I In ('cscript //nologo BrowseFolder.vbs') Do Set _FolderName=%%I

set dest=%_FolderName%

md "%dest%\UserBackup" &md "%dest%\UserBackup\Favorites" &ROBOCOPY /E /XJ "%userprofile%\Favorites" "%dest%\UserBackup\Favorites"
```

Code: (VBS Script) - Save as "BrowseFolder.vbs"If you want to run it as an example.

```
Const MY_COMPUTER = &H11&
Const WINDOW_HANDLE = 0
Const OPTIONS = 0

Set objShell = CreateObject("Shell.Application")
Set objFolder = objShell.Namespace(MY_COMPUTER)
Set objFolderItem = objFolder.Self
strPath = objFolderItem.Path

Set objShell = CreateObject("Shell.Application")
Set objFolder = objShell.BrowseForFolder _
(WINDOW_HANDLE, "Please select the destination for your data:", OPTIONS, strPath)

If objFolder Is Nothing Then
Wscript.Quit
End If

Set objFolderItem = objFolder.Self
objPath = objFolderItem.Path

Wscript.Echo objPath
```

Thank you in advance!

Comment: By "script runs anyway", do you mean the batch continues to run?

Comment: Yes, it proceeds to copy the IE favorites without you choosing the location first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The windows batch still runs because you don't check if the variable passed back is [empty or not](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2541767/what-is-the-proper-way-to-test-if-variable-is-empty-in-a-batch-file). The cancel button on the VBs Script will only cancel the VBS Script.

Try this in your windows batch file:

```
For /F "Tokens=1 Delims=" %%I In ('cscript //nologo BrowseFolder.vbs') Do Set _FolderName=%%I

IF [%_FolderName%] == [] GOTO EndBatch

set dest=%_FolderName%

md "%dest%\UserBackup" &md "%dest%\UserBackup\Favorites" &ROBOCOPY /E /XJ "%userprofile%\Favorites" "%dest%\UserBackup\Favorites"

:EndBatch
```

Comment: That works great! Makes sense and I wasn't seeing it at all.