# batch script conditions on variables

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

I want to use the first argument of my batch script as a variable. If it contains FULL I will set all my variables to 1 and if it's empty I will ask for each.

But I can't make my code work :

```
 @echo off
        color 02

    ::-----------------------------------------
    :: Variables
    set Preset=%1 
    set Profile=%2 
    set NeedToPassTheTests=1
    set PublishAPI=0

    REM ---------------------
REM We fill the variables depending on the arguments
echo(%1
if defined Preset (

if "%Preset%"=="FULL" (
echo FULL
set PublishOCPP=1
set NeedToPassTheTests=1 
set PublishAPI=1
)

) else (
    REM No preset so we are going to ask
    set /p PublishAPI="Publish API ? (0 or 1).............. ? "
    set /p NeedToPassTheTests="Test the projects before ? (0 or 1).............. ? "
)


echo NeedToPassTheTests %NeedToPassTheTests% 
echo %PublishAPI%

echo.
pause
```

I get

> **The syntax of the command is incorrect**

And also my echo at the end are not printing the value (when I remove my ifs) it only displays echo is off.

I'm starting with .bat files, I've tried with only the is Empty test (taken from here : [What is the proper way to test if variable is empty in a batch file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2541767/what-is-the-proper-way-to-test-if-variable-is-empty-in-a-batch-file) ) and it doesn't work either.

Do you know why ?

**UPDATE :**
It works when I pass FULL as argument but my variables are not updated. however it the parameter is empty it doesn't work (ie doesn't ask me to fill the variables).

Comment: Don't use `::comment` within a *code block* (parenthesised sequence of statements) - use `rem ` The `::` is a broken label and labels within code blocks can lead to unexpected results.

Comment: Use the syntax `if "%varname%"=="value" (dothis) else (dothat)` to compare strings which may contain separators like spaces or you'll get a syntax error. The quotes cause the contained values to be interpreted as a single string.

Comment: if "%Preset%"=="" also gives me an error with incorrect syntax :(

Comment: Please show the entire code line. What is the content of `preset`?

Comment: it's in my initial post, Preset contains %1

Comment: `%1` means the first parameter to the batch file. What parameters were you giving the batch file, ie your invocation line is *thisbatch whatisthisvalue*

Comment: Empty in my example, I want to be able to check if it's empty.

Comment: Further problem with your code structure. The `(` for the `if` must be on the same line as the `if` and the string `) else (` must also all be on one line

Comment: you may be interested to use [choice](https://ss64.com/nt/choice.html) instead of `set /p`: no wrong inputs possible.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure which errors are in the code but I can see several bugs in a second.

`set NeedToPassTheTests=1` will set the variable called `NeedToPassTheTests` to the value `1`

`set NeedToPassTheTests<space>=1` will set `NeedToPassTheTests<space>` to `1`

`set NeedToPassTheTests<space>=<space>1` will set `NeedToPassTheTests<space>` to `<space>1`.

So first of all, get rid of any unnecessary spaces.

Answer (score 0):

```
set NeedToPassTheTests = 1
```

Remove the spaces. Batch is sensitive to spaces on **oth** sides of the assignment - you are setting a variable named "NeedToPassTheTests<kbd>space</kbd>" to a value of "<kbd>space</kbd>1"

To test for variable `var` is empty:

```
if defined var (echo variable is not empty) else (echo variable is empty)
```

Quirk:

```
echo(%var%
```

will show the variable if it's not empty or an empty line if it is (not the `echo` status)

Comment: I don't have an error anymore my bad. But when my variable is empty (no arguments passed, echo %1 show "ECHO is off" it's considered not empty.

Comment: With an empty argument, `echo` shows the current `echo` status (on or off) Use `echo(%1` (or `echo(%potentiallyemptyvariable%`) which will yield an empty line if the argument evaluates to *nothing* Note that the `(` is required for this.

Comment: Yes it's empty :) But it doesn't go in the else, please see my update code

Comment: Use the syntax like `"set Preset=%1"` on all string-set instructions. Your code contains trailing spaces on lines, so `preset` is being set to <kbd>Space</kbd> which is a little hard to see but is a value, so `preset` **is** defined. (and yes - this can be a real head-scratcher. Using the quotes becomes Pavlovian after you've spent hours trying to figure it out...)