# Windows 7 batch files: How to check if parameter has been passed to batch file

Tags: windows-7, batch-file

Back in the mid-90's, I remember doing something like this:

```
if %1==. dir
```

basically, if you put the above code in `dodir.bat` and run it on its own without passing it any parameters, it would run the dir command.  However, if you passed it anything at all as a parameter, it would not run the dir command.

I can't seem to get this to work in my Windows 7 batch files.  Perhaps I don't remember the proper syntax.  Any helpers?

Comment: a "catch all" example: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/830565/how-do-i-check-that-a-parameter-is-defined-when-calling-a-batch-file/34552964#34552964

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Actually it was `if %1.==. command` (note the `.` after `%1`) back then. And you can use that now in Windows 7, it should work.

Example usage:

```
if %1.==. (
    echo No parameters have been provided.
) else (
    echo Parameters:
    echo %*
)
```

Comment: What does the period stand for?

Comment: @RishabhBhatnagar: I don't believe it stands for anything specific. It's there simply to avoid syntax error in case `%1` evaluates to an empty string. It could be some other character, and indeed I've seen others used (e.g. `if %1A==A`), but `.` has probably been used most often in this particular pattern. Note that this pattern was prevalent in the past, in the DOS era. Nowadays, `if "%~1"==""`, as [suggested by Tolga](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16819109/297408), would be the preferred method.

Answer (score 70):

`if %1.==. dir` will break if the parameter includes various symbols like `"`, `<`, etc

`if "%1"==""` will break if the parameter includes a quote (`"`).

Use `if "%~1"==""` instead:

```
if "%~1"=="" (
    echo No parameters have been provided.
) else (
    echo Parameters: %*
)
```

This should work on all versions of Windows and DOS.

Unit Test:

```
C:\>test
No parameters have been provided.

C:\>test "Lots of symbols ~@#$%^&*()_+<>?./`~!, but works"
Parameters: "Lots of symbols ~@#$%^&*()_+<>?./`~!, but works"
```

Comment: Could you elaborate or pass a reference on what %~1 does?

Comment: @josejulio You can do "call /?" to get the details on all the fancy things you can do with parameters.  For %~1 it says: expands %1 removing any surrounding quotes (")

Answer (score 15):

Try surrounding in quotes:

```
if "%1"=="" (
    echo "nothing was passed"
) else (
    echo "a parameter was passed"
    dir
)
```

You can take the echo's out, I just put them there for educational purposes.