# Using Batch file SHIFT command

Tags: batch-file, cmd

I'm trying to display up to 9 parameters across the screen, 
and then display one fewer on each following line, until there are none left.

I tried this:

```
@echo off
echo %*
shift
echo %*
shift
echo %*
```

Actual Result:

```
   a b c d e f
   a b c d e f
```

Expected Result:

```
A B C D E F
B C D E F
C D E F
D E F
E F
F
```

Any help?

Thanks.

Comment: @david Thanks for the instructions, I get it now. Thanks a lot.

    ECHO %1 %2 %3 %4 %5 %6 %7 %8 %9
    shift
    ECHO %1 %2 %3 %4 %5 %6 %7 %8 %9
    shift
    ECHO %1 %2 %3 %4 %5 %6 %7 %8 %9

Comment: a nice "catch all" example: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/830565/how-do-i-check-that-a-parameter-is-defined-when-calling-a-batch-file/34552964#34552964

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Shift doesn't change the actual order, just the index/pointer into the arguments.

Try this:

```
@echo off
echo %1
shift 
echo %1
shift
echo %1
echo %*
```

And you get this:

```
a
b
c
a b c d
```

Answer (score 16):

`SHIFT` is worthwhile if you want to get the value of `%1`, `%2`, etc.  It doesn't affect `%*`.  This script gives you the output you expect.

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

set args=0
for %%I in (%*) do set /a "args+=1"
for /l %%I in (1,1,%args%) do (
    set /a idx=0
    for %%a in (%*) do (
        set /a "idx+=1"
        if !idx! geq %%I set /p "=%%a "<NUL
    )
    echo;
)
```

Output:

```
C:\Users\me\Desktop>test a b c d e f
a b c d e f
b c d e f
c d e f
d e f
e f
f
```

Answer (score 4):

"Shift has no affect on the %* batch parameter"

Source: http://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/percent.mspx?mfr=true

I suggest altering your code to a loop or something

Answer (score 4):

The `%*` always prints all arguments from the command line (except `%0`). It does not honor the SHIFT command.

You need to explictly echo all arguments by position: `%1 %2 %3...`

```
@echo off
:loop
if "%~1" neq "" (
  echo %1 %2 %3 %4 %5 %6 %7 %8 %9
  shift
  goto :loop
)
```